# Getting webpage elements by class using Keyboard Maestro

Tags: keyboard-maestro

I frequently go to a library results page that has two pieces of information I want:

- The Listing Title: An `<h1>` with `class="title"`
- The Call Number: A `<td>` with `class="call"`

I want to be able to automatically copy the content of these two elements to a couple of named clipboards. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Awesome person, ComplexPoint, answered this on the KM forums [here](http://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/macro-request-get-webpage-elements-by-class/1407/4)

```
(function (strPath) {
  var r = document.evaluate(strPath, document, null, 0, null),
  lst = [],
  oNode;

  while (oNode = r.iterateNext()) {
  lst.push(oNode.className + ' = ' +oNode.textContent);
  }

  return lst.join('\n');
  })("//h1[@class='title'] | //td[@class='call']")
```